# How to prevent a c++ program to stop when click on the window?

Tags: c++, windows

I am using CodeBlocks to complie my c++ programs.

When I run the .exe file and click on the window, the program is stopping (is that normal ?).

> How do I prevent the program to stop when I click on it ? Or how do I make the program continue after clicking on it ?

**EDIT:** for example with this minimal code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while (true)
        std::cout << "*";
}
```

When I run the program, it should run endlessly, but whenever I leftclick inside the window opened by the program, it kills the program.
Is that intended, or is that to some sort of bug ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Possibly too broad. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Try to run your program in some terminal..... thru some command....

Comment: My crystal ball says that you need to right click on the title bar of the console, open settings, then disable mouse selection.

Comment: It could be operating system specific, and your question does not mention any OS. BTW, a program can be started without any mouse (e.g. on some command line), and some computers (e.g. web servers) don't have mouses.

Comment: My OS is Windows 10. This problem occurs either when I run the program by double clicking on the .exe file, or when i run the program thrus the command terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't "kill" your program; it only suspends it. You can press Enter, and your program will resume.

---

This is a feature of Windows. When it runs a program in the console (aka the "black window"), it lets you grab the output of the program by selecting a rectangular region by dragging with the left mouse button.

[image: Marking in Windows console]

This is what annoys you. Windows thinks you want to select a region in the output window, but you don't want to do it - you only want to click the window (e.g. to bring it above other windows). To fix this, disable the "Quick Edit" mode by right-clicking on the window's title, and Choosing "Properties", "Options", "Edit Options", "QuickEdit Mode".

[image: Quick Edit]

It seems that Windows remembers this setting, so you only need to do it "once" (until you decide that you actually need this feature back).